# find max/min points of $f=z^2 - 2$ in the circle {$z:|z| \leq 1$}

Tags: complex-analysis

find where(in what points) $|f(z)|$ get it maximum and minimum of $f=z^2 - 2$ in the circle {$z:|z| \leq 1$}

I guess that according to the theory those points must be on the circle $|z| = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must have $|z|=1$. But this implies that $|z^2|=1$ too. Now you can draw a diagram of the possible positions of the points $z^2-2$ in the complex plane and see geometrically which of them are closest to / furthest from $0$.